# WCF and receive data by url

Tags: c#, wcf

I have program that send data to URL, so after research I find out that I should set WCF service to receive that data. But I'm green in WCF so can you support me with some tips and code how to write service that on specyfic URL will be receiving byte list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here, step by step guidance provided for you to create WCF restful service

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/105273/Create-RESTful-WCF-Service-API-Step-By-Step-Guide

Answer (score 0):

So it displays xml and json file, but what when I whant to receive from sending program (by uri) xml file (it sends closed file, not contain) and save it on server where wcf app is working?