# Request JSON data in WCF REST Service and call through jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, json, wcf

I am developing a scenario in which I have to insert the data in xml file.

Following is my service contract:

```
namespace WcfService1
{   
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
       [OperationContract]
       [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "PostData")]
       string InsertData(Data data);
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class Data
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Category { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Mobile { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My Config file:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
<add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="b_WebHttpBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
    openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
    allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
    maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" transferMode="Buffered"
    useDefaultWebProxy="true" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
      maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
        realm="" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
   <behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="web">
      <webHttp />
   </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour" name="WcfService1.Service1">
          <endpoint address="WcfServiceAddress" behaviorConfiguration="web" binding="webHttpBinding"
  bindingConfiguration="b_WebHttpBinding" contract="WcfService1.IService1" />
  </service>
    </services>
    <protocolMapping>
    <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
</protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>

    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I am calling it through the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#BtnRegister').click(function () {
            debugger;
            var input =
                {
                    data:
                        {
                            Name: document.getElementById("TxtUserName").value,
                            Email: document.getElementById("TxtUserEmail").value,
                            Category: document.getElementById("TxtUserCategory").value,
                            Mobile: document.getElementById("TxtUserMobile").value,
                            Message: document.getElementById("message").value,
                        }
                };
            $.ajax({

                type: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost:22727/Service1.svc/WcfServiceAddress/PostData",
                contentType: "application/json",
                data: JSON.stringify(input),
                success: function (result) {
                    alert("data");
                },
                error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert(textStatus + ':' + errorThrown); }
            });
        });
    });
```

But the data is not inserting in the file.

Comment: You cannot access a POST method by giving the url in browser. Use tools like Fiddler to do that

Comment: You can also use REST Console(chrome plugin) https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/rest-console/cokgbflfommojglbmbpenpphppikmonn?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var input = 
{
  Name: document.getElementById("TxtUserName").value,
  Email: document.getElementById("TxtUserEmail").value,
  Category: document.getElementById("TxtUserCategory").value,
  Mobile: document.getElementById("TxtUserMobile").value,
  Message: document.getElementById("message").value,
}

var jsonInput = JSON.stringify(input)
```

Then in your ajax call

```
  $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:22727/Service1.svc/WcfServiceAddress/PostData",
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: { data : jsonInput } ,
            success: function (result) {
                alert("data");
            },
            error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert(textStatus + ':' + errorThrown); }
        });
```

Also, put a break point on your method in WCF and see if your Data object is actually getting mapped properly with the input you are sending. I reckon that in your WCF method, the Data argument is coming as null

Hope it helps.

Comment: No, still the same problem. The data is not saving in the file and i have also put the breakpoint in the method in my service. But the debugger do not go there

Answer (score 0):

check out this

/service1.svc/WcfServiceAddress/help

this will return of list of method in your WCF service with passing para

my service endpoint declaration

```
<service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour" name="DataService.DataService">
    <endpoint address="web" behaviorConfiguration="jsonBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="webHttpBindingWithJsonP" contract="DataService.IDataService"/>
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBinding" contract="DataService.IDataService"  />
    <endpoint address="soap" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="DataService.IDataService"/>
  </service>
```

Comment: When i have tried the given url of yours. The browser shows that Endpoint not found

Comment: try help command and if not shows any method then remove behaviorConfiguration and set GET method instead of POST and check

Comment: I have to remove the behaviorConfiguration from both services and endpointaddress?

Comment: i followed your url, it is showing the following : 

"Sendera:DestinationUnreachableThe message with To 'http://localhost:22727/Service1.svc/WcfServiceAddress/help' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to an AddressFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher.  Check that the sender and receiver's EndpointAddresses agree."

Comment: I am sharing my endpoint setting. Please match with your configuration

Comment: Ok @Rachit Patel. I will. Please share

Comment: may this reference URL will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24061122/wcf-and-receive-data-by-url/24061170#24061170